# Why i am not getting dropdown in react js can any one solve me this

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest

I want to get a drop down but i am not getting it. The api is being called but its not being diaplayed on dropdown. I an new to react can any one rewrite the code for me.

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
    import axios from 'axios';
    
function App() {
    const handleSelect=()=> {
        axios
        .get("https://cdndemo-api.co-vin.in/api/v2/admin/location/states")
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response.data);
          setState(response.data);
     });
    }
    const [state, setState] = useState([]);
  return <div>
      <select  onChange={handleSelect}
      >
        click
        <option value="">Choose a user</option>

      {state?.states?.map((value) => {
        return (
          <div>
            <option value={value.state_name} key={value.state_id}>{value.state_name}</option>
          </div>
        );
      })}
       </select>
  </div>;
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to keep your state's data type equal to the data type of the API response.

> If the data you get from the API is an array then you can do something like this:

```
import React,{useState, useEffect} from 'react';
    import axios from 'axios';
    
function App() {
     //set initial state as []
    const [state, setState] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
        axios
        .get("https://cdndemo-api.co-vin.in/api/v2/admin/location/states")
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response.data);
          // if response.data is an type of an array use this
          setState(response.data);
     });
  }, []);

  return <div>
      <select
      >
        click
        <option value="">Choose a user</option>

       {/* Your mapping */}

      {state.length > 0 && state.map((value) => {
        return (
            <option value={value.state_name} key={value.state_id}>{value.state_name}</option>
    
        );
      })}
       </select>
  </div>;
}

export default App
```

> If your data type is an Object then you can do something like the

```
    import React,{useState, useEffect} from 'react';
    import axios from 'axios';
function App() {
    //set initial state as null
    const [state, setState] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
        axios
        .get("https://cdndemo-api.co-vin.in/api/v2/admin/location/states")
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response.data);
          // if response.data is an type of an object use this
          setState(response.data);
     });
  }, []);

  return <div>
      <select
      >
        click
        <option value="">Choose a user</option>

       {/* Your mapping */}

      {state && state.states.map((value) => {
        return (
         
            <option value={value.state_name} key={value.state_id}>{value.state_name}</option>
          
        );
      })}
       </select>
  </div>;
}

export default App
```

Comment: Still not getting

Comment: What's your API response?

Comment: {"states":[{"state_id":1,"state_name":"Andaman and Nicobar Islands"},{"state_id":2,"state_name":"Andhra Pradesh"},{"state_id":3,"state_name":"Arunachal Pradesh"},{"state_id":4,"state_name":"Assam"},{"state_id":5,"state_name":"Bihar"},{"state_id":6,"state_name":"Chandigarh"},{"state_id":7,"state_name":"Chhattisgarh"},{"state_id":8,"state_name":"Dadar and Nagar Haveli"},{"state_id":54,"state_name":"Dadra and Nagar Haveli"},{"state_id":37,"state_name":"Daman and Diu"},{"state_id":9,"state_name":"Delhi"},{"state_id":80,"state_name":"Demo"}

Comment: instead of making an api request in handle select use useEffect hook to make a request when the page loads. also, make sure that the response.data is not a string. If it is a string do setState(JSON.parse(response.data))

Comment: Sir can you please rewrite it for me i have used use effect but i am not getting it its a request

Comment: Yes sure but can you tell me what your response type. Is it a string or is it an object?

Comment: Yes its object.

Comment: changed the code please try now

Comment: I am getting it consoled as {states:Array(67) }

Comment: Ok   try the updated version.

Comment:  great i saw some unnecessary divs in your return which i think were causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```js
import "./styles.css";
import axios from "axios";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos").then((res) => {
      setState(res.data);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <select>
        {state.map((item) => (
          <option value={item.name} key={item.id}>
            {item.title}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Uncaught type error state. Map is not a function

Comment: While i have entred your code

Comment: so response coming as an object, convert response object to an array before map state
https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-kowalevski-8dixk

Comment: Means i cant get you